# Equation form for a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to get an equation representing the following series:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n X \cdot \frac{Y-\lfloor k/2\rfloor}{100}$$

Also, and just a plus but not really much important, how could I leave open the initial $K$ value to be $0/1$ instead of always $0$?

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$\lfloor k/2 \rfloor = k/2 - 1/4 + (-1)^k/4$$
So $$\eqalign{\sum_{k=0}^n X \cdot \frac{Y - \lfloor k/2 \rfloor}{100} &= (n+1) \frac{XY}{100} - \frac{X}{100} \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{k}{2} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{(-1)^k}{4}\right)\cr
&= (n+1) \frac{XY}{100} - \frac{X}{100} \left( \frac{n^2}{4} - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{(-1)^n}{8} \right)}$$

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking in the second question.  If you want to start the sum at $k=1$ instead of $k=0$, just subtract the $k=0$ term, which is $XY/100$.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your quick response. It took a lot for me to validate this because I was getting weird result while applying your equation to my expected results until i realized that my original series expression was wrong and it was supposed to be _capped in n-1, not n_. I **replaced n by n-1** in your solution and worked like a charm. Thanks again, setting this as correct answer.